# What is the maximal density vertex subset of the 8-connected grid with induced vertex degrees $\leq 4$?

Tags: reference-request, open-problems

Let $G$ be the infinite graph defined by
[8-connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity#8-connected)
of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.
What is the maximal density vertex subset whose induced subgraph has maximum degree $\leq 4$?  More precisely, what is the maximal density $\delta(4)$ as defined
[in this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.45.237) which gives the bounds $\frac{3}{5} \leq \delta(4) \lt \frac{5}{8}$?

This question could be known to be open, and it has been
[asked on math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74476).

To make this question less dry I am adding an example of a periodic tiling which meets the $\frac{3}{5}$ lower bound, and additional tilings with this density are given in the paper linked above.  I do not know if a pattern has been found with a higher density subject to the degree constraint, or whether the strictness of the $\frac{3}{5}$ bound has been proved.

```
. . X X X . . X X X
X X . . X X X . . X
. X X X . . X X X .
X . . X X X . . X X
X X X . . X X X . .
. . X X X . . X X X
X X . . X X X . . X
. X X X . . X X X .
X . . X X X . . X X
X X X . . X X X . .
```